Using Excel Pivot Table to find percent of a sub category
I have a data set of patient responses to a drug every two weeks for a total of 32 weeks. The response is either Positive or Negative, and I've created a Pivot Table where the rows are patient IDs and the columns are the weeks.
I created a Pivot Table filtered on test results and can get the Pivot Table to show me counts of the "Negative" result per patient per week (showing only "Negative" results via the filter). But what I want is to show this as a percent of the total number of evaluations for each specific patient. All of the calculation options won't let me calculate the percent of negative results with respect to all test results for that patient for that week (so I want it to calculate [count of negative results for week 1 for patient 1/total count of tests for week 1 for patient 1]. I can do this by manipulating the Pivot Table of counts (showing counts of Negative tests, Positive Tests, and Total Tests per week) I created, but wondered if there was a faster way to do this in a Pivot Table by calculating using a filtered value.

Please show your inputs, desired outputs and your own effort so far.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
